# flutter lists and provider how to update provider variables from a list?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a list in a changenotifier called my list. this list takes a class called listitem which is two variables for this demonstration called variable 1 and variable 2. here is my list and the listitem class.

```
List<ListItem> MyList = [
ListItem(
      variable1: 2,
      variable2: true),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 5,
      variable2: false),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 1,
      variable2: true),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 7,
      variable2: true),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 2,
      variable2: false),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 3,
      variable2: true),
];

class ListItem {
  int variable1;
  bool variable2;
  

  ListItem({
    required this.variable1,
    required this.variable2,
    
  });
}
```

In my UI page, i'm creating a list of tiles using ListView.builder and what I want to happen is that when the button is pressed from the listview, I want it to update a set of variables in a change notifier. (this changenotifier is also where the list is housed.

so in my change notifier I have the following:

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

int _variable1 = 0;
bool _variable2 = false;

int get variable1 => _variable1;
bool get variable2 => _variable2;

void UpdateList(ListItem index){
_variable1 = MyList[index.variable1].variable1;
_variable2 = MyList[index.variable2].variable2;
    notifyListeners();
}

List<ListItem> MyList = [
ListItem(
      variable1: 2,
      variable2: true),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 5,
      variable2: false),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 1,
      variable2: true),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 7,
      variable2: true),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 2,
      variable2: false),
  ListItem(
      variable1: 3,
      variable2: true),
];

}
```

so when a button is pressed in the UI, it runs the UpdateList function but the bool and int variable in the changenotifier don't update to what is represented in the ListItem of that choice.

thanks so much and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your method to this to update the variables in `MyProvider`.
There is a note to notify in Dart to use lowerCamelCase for method and variable names:

```
void updateList(ListItem item) {
  _variable1 = item.variable1;
  _variable2 = item.variable2;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

and in your page when you want to update your list use `updateList` method of your provider and pass the selected `ListItem` as its arg.

if you had any question please ask.

Happy coding...